# Load javascript with html page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and just started getting my hands dirty in it. I have downloaded angular-seed and started changing in it. I have a navbar which displays different html pages when user navigate. The problem is the page is getting loaded properly but i have some javascript in the script tag in that html page that is not loading, and its also not throwing any error in the console.
Here is my index.html

```
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style1.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/view1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/view2">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>


  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my app.js

'use strict';

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Here is my view1.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {


}]);
```

Here is my view1.html which contains a javascript script tag in it:

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="charts">
                    <div class="col-md-4 charts-grids stats-widget ">
                        <div class="sparkline">
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-3x" ></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stats1"class="stats_box">
                            <span class="info-box-text">Number of sign-ups</span>
                            <span id="sign-up" class="percent">56,000</span>
                        </div>
                            <i id="red" class="fa fa-circle-o text-red" value="11000"></i>
                            <i id="yellow" class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow" value="12000"></i>
                            <i id="green" class="fa fa-circle-o text-green" value="13000"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 charts-grids stats-widget states-mdl">
                        <div class="sparkline">
                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stats2" class="stats_box">
                            <span class="info-box-text">Daily active users</span>
                            <span id="active" class="percent">23,000</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='firstbox' id='fb2' >
                            <i id="red" class="fa fa-circle-o text-red" value="21000"></i>
                            <i id="yellow" class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow" value="22000"></i>
                            <i id="green" class="fa fa-circle-o text-green" value="23000"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 charts-grids stats-widget">
                        <div class="sparkline">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stats3"class="stats_box">
                            <span class="info-box-text">Average time active</span>
                            <span class="percent">80,000</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='firstbox' id='fb3'>
                            <i id="red" class="fa fa-circle-o text-red" value="31000"></i>
                            <i id="yellow" class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow" value="32000"></i>
                            <i id="green" class="fa fa-circle-o text-green" value="33000"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 charts-grids stats-widget ">
                        <div class="sparkline">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stats4" class="stats_box">
                            <span class="info-box-text">Total time run</span>
                            <span class="percent">39,000</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='firstbox' id='fb4' >
                            <i id="red" class="fa fa-circle-o text-red" value="41000"></i>
                            <i id="yellow" class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow" value="42000"></i>
                            <i id="green" class="fa fa-circle-o text-green" value="43000"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 charts-grids stats-widget states-mdl">
                        <div class="sparkline">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stats5"class="stats_box">
                            <span class="info-box-text">Total distance covered</span>
                            <span id="distance"class="percent">20,000</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='firstbox' id='fb5' >
                            <i id="red" class="fa fa-circle-o text-red" value="51000"></i>
                            <i id="yellow" class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow" value="52000"></i>
                            <i id="green" class="fa fa-circle-o text-green" value="53000"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 charts-grids stats-widget">
                        <div class="sparkline">
                            <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stats6"class="stats_box">
                            <span class="info-box-text">10K activated</span>
                            <span id="activated"class="percent">26,000</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='firstbox' id='fb6' >
                            <i id="red" class="fa fa-circle-o text-red" value="61000"></i>
                            <i id="yellow" class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow"  value="62000"></i>
                            <i id="green" class="fa fa-circle-o text-green"value="63000"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div><!--end charts-->
                </div><!--end row-->
<script>
            var barChartData = {
                labels : ["No. of sign-ups","Daily active users","Average time active","Total time run","Total distance covered","10K activated"],
                datasets : [
                                {
                                    fillColor : "#dd4b39",
                                    strokeColor : "#dd4b39",
                                    data : [10000,13000,56081,42001,5000,40000]
                                },
                                {
                                    fillColor : "#f39c12",
                                    strokeColor : "#f39c12",
                                    data : [40000,70000,55000,21001,45023,70121,60093]
                                },
                                {
                                    fillColor : "#00a65a",
                                    strokeColor : "#00a65a",
                                    data : [43010,75432,50966,66300,39000,12010,33098]
                                }
                            ]   
                                };
                new Chart(document.getElementById("bar").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);           
        </script>
```

Comment: are you sure that path for those js files are correct??

Comment: Its not the js file its the javascript under the script tag in view1.html is not loading

Comment: @gauravtiwari yes it will not be executed, put all your js in the shell page. js must be loaded upon bootstrapping of application, for that you will use on-demand coding style. see require js

Comment: @katana does this also work based on routes.

Comment: @gauravtiwari yes it will work, for now just put all your js files in your index.html. All this js files are accessible by view1

Comment: @katana thanx for guiding me.

Comment: @Katana can you provide me some link of requirejs to learn more about it.

Comment: @gauravtiwari http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html please take a look of this